# Richfaces rendering is not working with websphere 8 after migration

Tags: richfaces, rendering, websphere-7, websphere-8

we are using Richfaces 3.3.3 and webspheare 8 with RAD 8.0.3.

we are facing some difficulties when we are running application in WAS8. below are those:

- we are getting FileNotFound exception for some JavaScript files and some Images (not for all images used in Application) (error code -  SRVE8109W).
- Also rendering is not happening on clicking on buttons (we are rendering the items using AJAX that come with Richfaces).

Could any one please help me out with these issues. and also, appriciate any suggestions/recomandations on moving WAS 7 to WAS 8 with Richfaces applications.

**Note:** All these are woking fine with WAS 7 & RAD 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

@user958340 - The conflict will be between RichFaces 3.3.3.Final and WAS 8.x.x's implementation of MyFaces 2.0.4.  Unless you used JSF 2.0 in WAS 7 (via a Shared Library) and setting the Classloader Policy to PARENT_LAST, then you were using either sun-ri (JSF 1.1) or MyFaces 1.2.  I've gotten RichFaces 3.3.3.Final to work with MyFaces 1.2 on WAS 6.1 and WAS 7.

However, I didn't get WAS 8 and RichFaces 3.3.3.Final to play nicely either.  Being as RichFaces 3.3.3.Final was so buggy, imho, I used that opportunity to test drive RichFaces 4 and PrimeFaces 3.x (I chose PrimeFaces).  RichFaces 4 was a complete rewrite due to ajax being better supported in JSF 2.0, particularly with partial-state saving.

Even though it would/will be a pain, I'd suggest upgrading RichFaces or migrating to another framework like PrimeFaces.